# Get Nav Drawer to slide beneath Toolbar/Actionbar

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I've been working on the material design overhaul of my app. I curious to how you would change the activity_main xml code to get the nav drawer to slide open without covering the toolbar which contains that gorgeous new toggle button. Any Ideas how I can do this?

activity_main:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawerView"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="@drawable/nav_border"
        android:divider="@null" />
</RelativeLayout>
<!--
     <fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:name="com.shamu11.madlibsportable.MadlibsSelect"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
-->

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have achieved it using following layout:
Drawer.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.toolbar.Drawer" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool1"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />



    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tool1" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <!-- Nav drawer -->

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/drawerList"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:divider="@android:color/white"
            android:dividerHeight="8dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:headerDividersEnabled="true" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app1:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app1:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: voted up, but cannot accept it as answer not my question.. I guess shamu11 can

Answer (score 1):

The material design guidelines say navigation drawer should overlay on top of everything. Google has been inconsistent with their apps; however, i believe they are going to fix all their apps to the nav drawer overlays.

> The nav drawer spans the full height of the screen and the drawer is behind the status bar.
>   http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: I really like what they did with google play despite the inconsistency. I think it would go well with my drawer. Any way of doing this?

Comment: I would advise against using it. However, if you want to anyway, check out this answer. Hope it helps! ^_^ http://goo.gl/28XzLa

I also saw this github project that does the same thing. https://github.com/ikimuhendis/LDrawer